# separating php array value

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have this array in php:

```
$a[]="Jason White";
$a[]="Jean Black";
$a[]="Billy Brown";
```

But I will have to display the values in the table and should be like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| Firstname | Lastname     |
+-----------+--------------+
| Jason     | White        |
+-----------+--------------+
| Jean      | Black        |
+-----------+--------------+
| Billy     | Brown        |
+-----------+--------------+
```

is it possible to do it that way?
or any suggestion to make this table?

thanks in advance.

Comment: yes its possible, by using simple `foreach` and `explode` you can do this such as `list($firstname, $latname) = explode(" ", $var)`

Comment: Yes is the answer to your question. However, you haven't tried something.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($a as $name) {
   echo "<tr>";
   $name_arr = explode(" ",$name);
   echo "<td>".$name_arr[0]."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$name_arr[1]."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks mate. But what if I would like to display only 1 row for example.

Answer (score 0):

explode it with space and display it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. This example assumes that texts 'Firstname' and 'Lastname' does not have to be generated from PHP:

```
<?php
$a = array
(
  'Jason White',
  'Jean Black',
  'Billy Brown',
);
?>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
<?php
  foreach($a as $val)
  {
    // creates an array from a string 
    // basing on a string character 
    // to be used as an indicator of new array value
    $separate = explode(' ', $val);

    echo '<tr>';

    // to avoid 'undefined index' errors, 
    // loop through the array that was just created.
    foreach($separate as $display)
    {
      echo '<td>'. $display .'</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
  }
?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For splitting and storing the string into array use PHP function [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(" ", $var);
```